# What is the difference between known variables and unknown variables?

Tags: polynomials, terminology, definition

Also, From Wikipedia

> When writing polynomials, the coefficients are usually taken to be known and the indeterminates to be unknown, but depending on the problem, all variables may assume either role.

Isn't it is the case that coefficients are constants and not variable? What it is referring towards by 'inderminates'-variable?

Is it related to **dependent variable** and **independent variable**?

Comment: Well, what are *constants*? Are they really anything other than variables that we are thinking of as not changing? :)

Comment: Yes, constants represents fixed numbers whose values are not changing in an expression.

Comment: What does "values are not changing" mean? As far as I know, there is no formal difference between a constant and a variable.

Comment: A variable is a symbol that can take many/all values in an expression from the given values but a symbol representing constant can take only one value among the given values it can hold.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how it might be the other way around - I want to model a particular set of data with a cubic function. So I have a set like $(1, 7), (2, 5), (3, 7), (4, 19)$, etc., and a function $y = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$. *In this context*, the $x$ and $y$ values are *known*, and the coefficients $a_0$ up to $a_3$ are *unknown*. What's more, by specifying a different data set (or even a different model), those coefficients can vary. And if they vary, then presumably they are *variables*.

Comment: What is meant by "different model"?

Comment: A different formula to explain the data. Like perhaps a higher degree polynomial, or something involving exponential functions.

Answer (score 0):

This mainly has to do with certain (quite vague) conventions in calculus.

In particular, if a test asks you to compute $$\frac{d}{dx}(ax^2),$$ the person marking the test probably wants to see $2ax$, not $$\frac{da}{dx}x^2+2ax.$$ That's because you're meant to treat $\frac{da}{dx}$ as being equal to zero, the intuitive explanation being that $a$ is "held constant" while $x$ varies.

(Unfortunately, this is never really made precise or rigorous.)